# Delphi Combined Array Images

Tags: image, delphi

How can I combine multiple images into one?
I have an array with a path to the images. These images want to be connected from the right. My images is `.png` format.

Thank you

My test code not working:

```
procedure TCreatorProject.MergeImageList(Images: TImagesList);
var
  Img,ImageOut: TGraphic;
  ImageTemp: TBitmap;
  I: Integer;
  FileOutput: String;
begin
  FileOutput := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'temp\tempimage.png';

  for I := Low(Images) to High(Images) do
    if not FileExists(Images[I]) then
      raise Exception.Create('Chyba: obrázek nebyl nalezen !');

  ImageTemp := TBitmap.Create;
  try

    for I := Low(Images) to High(Images) do
    begin
      Img.LoadFromFile(Images[I]);

      ImageTemp.Width := Img.Width;
      ImageTemp.Height := Img.Height;

      if I = 0 then
        ImageTemp.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, Img)
      else
        ImageTemp.Canvas.Draw(ImageTemp.Width, ImageTemp.Height, Img);
    end;

    ImageOut := TPNGObject.Create;

    ImageOut.Assign(ImageTemp);

    ImageOut.SaveToFile(FileOutput);
  finally
    ImageTemp.Free;
    Img.Free;
    ImageOut.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: i have test this code:

Comment: sorry for my question, i have an edit my post. Thanks

Comment: I see 2 problems: You are always drawing in the same place, and you don't enlarge the output image?

Comment: output image must be increased. Width output image must be : ImageTemp.Width := ImageTemp.Width + Img.Width;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are always drawing in the same place and you don't enlarge the output image.
Try this instead(Written and tested with DelphiXE7):

```
program SO32558735;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.IOUtils, System.Types, Vcl.Imaging.pngimage, Vcl.Graphics;

type
  TPngImages = array of TPngImage;

function LoadImages(Path : String) : TPngImages;

var
  Index   : Integer;
  Files   : TStringDynArray;

begin
 Files := TDirectory.GetFiles(Path, '*.png');
 SetLength(Result, Length(Files));
 for Index := Low(Files) to High(Files) do
  begin
   Result[Index] := TPngImage.Create;
   Result[Index].LoadFromFile(Files[Index]);
  end;
end;

function MergeImages(Images: TPngImages) : TPngImage;

var
  Image  : TPngImage;
  Bmp    : TBitmap;
  X      : Integer;

begin
 Result := TPngImage.Create;
 Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
 X := 0;
 try
  for Image in Images do
   begin
    // enlarge output image
    Bmp.Width := Bmp.Width+Image.Width;
    // adjust height if images are not equal
    if Image.Height > Bmp.Height then
     Bmp.Height := Image.Height;
    Bmp.Canvas.Draw(X, 0, Image);        
    X := Bmp.Width+1;
   end;
  Result.Assign(Bmp);
 finally
  Bmp.Free;
 end;
end;

var
 Images : TPngImages;
 Image  : TPngImage;

begin
  try
   try
    Images := LoadImages('<input path>');
    if Length(Images) < 1 then
     raise Exception.Create('No files found!');
    Image := MergeImages(Images);
    Image.SaveToFile('<output file>');
    Image.Free;
   finally
    for Image in Images do
     Image.Free;
   end;
  except
   on E: Exception do
    Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for your example, by this I understand it, and to me it works correctly.